# How to store 2D string array in a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, session

I have this 2D string array which is retrieving data from a database. Problem is, when i click a button, the array gets empty due to reload. I need to store it in a session or with any other way you guys suggest.

```
 //Declaration in the class 
 string[,] randomizedOptionalTable;



//In the function of retrieving the database
randomizedOptionalTable = new string[qIDSize, 4];
//Database retrieving code.
Session["keyRandomizedOptionalTable"] = randomizedOptionalTable;
```

I think what I'm storing in the Session is just the base address of the array.

I want the entire data to be stored in the Session. It would really help me if you guys have a solution for this or any different idea to store a string table with different way.

Comment: How you get it from the `Session`, can you post that code too?

Comment: { randomizedOptionalTable = (string[,])Session["keyRandomizedOptionalTable"]; }

Comment: Session can store complex objects, you should be able to retrive the data. Can you give a tiny example how the array is before and after?

Comment: That is when the 2D array is NULL at the form load. 
Just if else condition

Comment: The array is actually storing the answer options from a database. With 'n' rows and 4 columns for options A,B,C,D.

It is retrieving the data from DB. Because I created a label and printed the data on the page. Problem is when I click a button it loses all the data

Comment: The problem is only with 2D array?, have you tried to store something simple, like a number?

Comment: I have tried it with simple int variable, it is working fine. But not with any array.
I found a solution with array, but the array is initialized at the same time when it is assigned to the session. So that was not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the sample, working for me...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ToSession();
        FromSession();
    }
}
private void ToSession() 
{ 
    string[,] strTo2D = { {"A"}, {"B"} };
    Session["str2DArray"] = strTo2D; 
}
private void FromSession() 
{
    string[,] strFrom2D = (string[,])Session["str2DArray"];
    Response.Write(strFrom2D[0, 0].ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: It worked? I did the same thing, isn't working. Let me try again.

Comment: can u post a bit more code here? have you debugged the code?

Comment: It is working, I got the value at Response.Write();
Now I just need to fetch it to the radio buttons.
Thanks a lot man! :)