# Can we store 2d array in session in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I am logging in an web application and then I keep the session and lock the application then other user login and I also want to save its data into session without destroying first user's session. Can we put 2d array in session in CodeIgniter?

```
// ################# OLD CODE WORKING FOR 1 USER ONLY #################
$result = $this->loginModel->login($email, $password);

$this->session->set_userdata($result);

// ################# NEW CODE (1) TRYING FOR MULTIPLE USERS #################
$result = $this->loginModel->login($email, $password);

$data['users'] = array();
foreach ($data['users'] as $index)
{
    $data['users'][$index] = $result;
} 
$this->session->set_userdata($data['users']);

// ################# NEW CODE (2) TRYING FOR MULTIPLE USERS #################
$result = $this->loginModel->login($email, $password);

$data['users'] = array();
foreach ($data['users'] as $index)
{
    $data['users'][$index] = $result;
    $this->session->set_userdata($index,$result);
} 

// ################# SESSION FILE CODE #################
public function set_userdata($data, $value = NULL)
{
    if (is_array($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => &$value)
        {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }

        return;
     }

     $_SESSION[$data] = $value;
}
```

This stores 1 user data into session variable, I want multiple.

This is refference of C# [How to store 2D string array in a session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507001/how-to-store-2d-string-array-in-a-session)

There is hard coded 2d array [Store multidimension array in userdata session codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848067/store-multidimension-array-in-userdata-session-codeigniter)

In CodeIgniter user Guide https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

I didnt see anywhere 2d array defining in session in user guide.

Comment: yes max 2 users i will allow and restrict to not keep session more than 2  simultaneously sessions

Comment: just like windows,  having multiple user login system

Comment: how to store in session multiple user data as my code is not correct

Comment: A session provides persistence between a browser and a server. Each different browser maintains its own session/server instance. There's no connection between the different user sessions on different browsers. You probably should not allow multiple different users to log on from the same browser. I'm not sure it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multi-dimensional array as below.

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array("index_1"=>array("val1","val2","val3")));
```

Then you can use

```
$sess_data =  $this->session->userdata("index_1");

echo $sess_data[0];
echo $sess_data[1];
echo $sess_data[2];
```

Comment: can i store like this in session in loop $data['users'] = array();
            $data['users'][0] = $result;
            foreach ($data['users'] as $index)
            {
                $data['users'][$index+1] = $result;
                $this->session->set_userdata($index,$result);
            }

Comment: or this $data['users'] = array();
            $data['users'][0] = $result;
            for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($data['users']); $i++) {
                $data['users'][$index+1] = $result;
                $this->session->set_userdata($index,$result);
            }

Comment: i get error if i write this $sess_data =  $this->session->userdata();
            $i = 0;
            if(sizeof($sess_data) > 0){
                $i = sizeof($sess_data) + 1;
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata(array($i=>$result));
            print_r($sess_data[0]);
            exit();

Comment: Missing argument 1 for CI_Session::userdata()